# What's the rate limit of graph api? How long does graph api's access token expire?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, token, rate-limiting

1. What's the rate limit of graph api? 
   I have done a lot of searching and asking on the web. Some said 600calls/600secs, but I did not manage to find the official decalration of rate-limiting issues.
2. How long does graph api's access token expire?
   No being able to find it anywhere

Answer (score 1):

This limit is not mentioned anywhere in the documents. This limit is user specific i.e If u are making 600 calls in 600 secs for 1 or more tokens of a user. There can be a workaround by using tokens of different Apps but same user, if u need to make so many calls.

Answer (score 0):

1.I don't think there is any rate limit on the Graph API although they have some thresholds mentioned at **Facebook Platform Policies** stating

> If you exceed, or plan to exceed, any of the following thresholds please contact us as you may be subject to additional terms: (>5M MAU) or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day).

2.The access token (and not extended access token) has validity of 60 mins. You can also query [Facebook Token Debug API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/debugging-access-tokens/) for the exact token expiration. Although Facebook mentions this short duration in a range of 1 to 2 hours [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/), which can be used to [retrieve a extended access token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/) with validity of 60 days.